# What is the xpath for this element?

Tags: xpath

My document is having two input buttons, one is disable and other is not. I want to find the xpath of the button which is not disable.

My elements are :

```
<input type="Submit" name="Next" value="Next Page" class="Btn_Md">
<input type="Submit" name="Next" value="Next Page" class="Btn_Md" disabled>
```

I have tried like this :

//input[@name='Next'][not(contains(@disabled, "disabled"))]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//input[@name='Next'][not(@disabled)]
```